# Equal charging of new and old battery

Tags: battery-charging, batteries, battery-chemistry

I am using four "12volt" batteries of 150 amp hour each, for a 24 volt solar backup system of ouyback things since four years. Now i add 4 new batteries of same capacity to increase the backup time for the same 24 volt system.

I check the specific gravity of each battery cell when the state of charge is 100% shown by the charge controller. I found that sg value of the older batteries is always greater than the new one. The older battery has 1.280 sg value while the new has 1.25 sg value. I know this means the system can't charge equally to new and old battery. Can i solve with equal charge by using the charge mode "equalization mode"?

Comment: Maybe ask your mate3 device support? We do electronics design here...

Comment: I think we include battery characteristics in electronics design.

Answer (score 1):

The new batteries at 1.25 are not fully charged. You can fully charge the new batteries by disconnecting the old batteries.

Equalisation will also charge all the batteries, but won't equalize them. Equalisation is what you do when you have all of your batteries in one series string. There is no way to really equalize the charge when you have batteries in parallel -- that's why batteries are designed with the cells all in series.

With the batteries in parallel, what you should expect is that the new batteries will charge up more, and discharge more, than the old batteries. So you shouldn't expect the old and new batteries to ever have exactly the same sg.